# Can we use "What do you think (that) makes someone a hero?" without that?

Tags: grammar

I'm confused. My friend said that you can't exclude the word "that" since after it is a verb.

Comment: Hm, the case for removing the word "*that*" might be stronger than the case for retaining it. The version with *that* can be read as asking for some kind of hero-making *thought* (i.e. the act of *thinking* that resulted in turning someone into a hero).

Comment: Your friend's advice is not sound. The core question in your example is "What makes someone a hero?" The addition "do you think" is as much a parenthetical clause as "in your opinion" would be—although it would not work at the beginning of the sentence. The expressions "What, in your opinion, makes someone a hero?" and "What makes someone a hero, in your opinion?" would not take a _that_ after the word _opinion_. Similarly, "What, do you think, makes some one a hero?" and "What makes someone a hero, do you think?" do not take a _that_ after _think_ in either wording.

Answer (score 1):

You must exclude "that".  When it is retained, the result is ungrammatical. This has been called the *that*-trace effect.  Here is a discussion: [Pesetsky](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwixkJLBi4zUAhUmjlQKHRQ3CSYQFggvMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fling.auf.net%2Flingbuzz%2F002385%2Fcurrent.pdf&usg=AFQjCNFUs6A574VYYyUaAfhArY5FyqAXLw&sig2=ZgxLvgEOiQjmTEXzR7WcXg&cad=rja), and also see [the that-trace effect](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/That-trace_effect).

Answer (score 0):

While "that" can be eliminated, the result, "What do you think makes someone a hero?" is probably not the intended meaning. I suggest that the original sentence should have been, "What do you think, that that makes someone a hero?", which is is much more argumentative and critical of the subject of the question.